# What is a deep exhalation/inhalation?

Tags: human-biology, respiration, breathing, lungs

I tried to find the academic definition of `deep exhalation/inhalation` but found nothing special.

I speculate that the correct definition is as follows:

> • *Deep Exhalation*: Exhaling the air with effort as much as possible,
>   after a normal **"inhalation"**.
>
> • *Deep Inhalation*: Inhaling the air with effort as much as possible,
>   after a normal **"exhalation"**.

The corresponding **volumes** of the air which is being moved inside respiratory tracts would be:

V<sub>deep exhalation</sub> = `Tidal Volume` + `Expiratory reserve volume (ERV)`

V<sub>deep inhalation</sub> = `Tidal Volume` + `Inspiratory reserve volume (IRV)`

---

But, in case we define them as below, the previous conclusion regarding the **volumes** turns wrong and consequently should be revised.

> • *Deep Exhalation*: Exhaling the air with effort as much as possible,
>   after a normal **"exhalation"**.
>
> • *Deep Inhalation*: Inhaling the air with effort as much as possible,
>   after a normal **"inhalation"**.

V<sub>deep exhalation</sub> = `Expiratory reserve volume (ERV)`

V<sub>deep inhalation</sub> = `Inspiratory reserve volume (IRV)`

---

I think it's impossible to assess without any subtle definition. I'm really confused.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You should investigate the concept of a collapsed lung. I think that may allow you to answer your question.

Comment: @TheNate Thank you. I'll give it a try. In the meantime, possible to let me know if there's a more active biology forum to ask questions? It seems Stackexchange is not too crowded by biologists as much as by developers!

Answer (score 2):

*Deep inhalation* and *deep exhalation* are informal terms and cannot be defined by lung volumes, because saying *deep* by itself does not tell *how* deep.

In the first part of the question *deep* refers to *maximal:*

- *Deep inhalation* that means inhaling the air with effort as much as possible = *maximal inhalation*
- *Deep exhalation* that means exhaling the air with effort as much as possible = *maximal exhalation*

According to [Physiology, Residual Volume (StatPerls)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK493170/):

The volume of air in the lungs after **maximal expiration** is called **residual volume (RV).**

> Residual volume (RV) is the volume of air that remains in the lungs
>   after maximum forceful expiration. In other words, it is the volume of
>   air that cannot be expelled from the lungs. This volume remains
>   unchanged regardless of the lung volume at which expiration was
>   started.

The volume of air in the lungs after **maximal inspiration** is called **total lung capacity (TLC)**.

> TLC is the total volume of the lungs at maximal inspiration.

According to Merriam-Webster dictionary:

**[Expiratory reserve volume](https://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/expiratory%20reserve%20volume)** = the additional amount of air that can be expired from the lungs by determined effort *after normal expiration.*

**[Inspiratory reserve volume](https://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/inspiratory%20reserve%20volume)** = the maximal amount of additional air that can be drawn into the lungs by determined effort *after normal inspiration.*

### **Lung volumes:**

[image]

*Image source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lung_volumes), Creative Commons License*